# How to catch ffmpeg stream with OpenCV C API?

Tags: c, opencv, ffmpeg

I would like to read an ffmpeg stream from *OpenCV* **C API**.

The streamer I want to catch is generate using `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1"  -pix_fmt uyvy422 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.110:5000`

I try to read the stream with the following code

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h> //C API VideoCapture()

CvCapture* cap = cvCreateFileCaptureWithPreference("udp://192.168.1.110:5000", CV_CAP_FFMPEG);

cvGrabFrame(stream->cap);
IplImage* frame = cvRetrieveFrame(stream->cap, 0);
```

The problem is that frame is set to *NULL* and nothing is actually retrieved.

It will be straightforward using *C++* API, but I cannot use it in my project, I need the **C** API.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: Is it working with C++ or Python?

Comment: Yes, it works properly with the analogous code in both C++ and Python

Comment: Can you please add C++ or Python to your post to be used as reference?

Comment: C API was removed a few versions ago. you'll have to use ancient versions for which support has ended years ago. **do not expect this to work.** what you might want to do is to write your own wrapper functions around the C++ API. have one compilation unit that is C++, and that only **exports C functions**.